# Twilio Browser client Available or not

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

I am facing a problem with Twilio to detect the Twilio Browser client Available or not.

If Twilio client is not available then need to send the voicemail otherwise I am using to accept the call.

```
Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which Browser you are using, is client behind any NAT, Firewall, etc?. Can you enable debugs in setup methods. Twilio.Device.setup(token, { debug: true });

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need agent presence. There are a couple ways to go about this. One (Recommended) is to use Twilio TaskRouter. https://www.twilio.com/taskrouter. This will handle agent presence for you (online, offline, busy, etc..) and much more

Your other option is to use a service like PubNub http://www.pubnub.com/ and bind the clint so you can get state information (online, offline, busy, etc..). This is more wok since you have to handle state yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps can be followed to achieve this
 1. Set a valid url to the action attribute of the Dial verb of the client
  Eg., The TwiMl to dial the client must be
  <Response>
   <Dial action="myapp/statusCallBack">
    <Client>jenny</Client>
   </Dial>
  </Response>  
 2.    If the client jenny is available, the connection object can be received via
  Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn){conn.accept();});
 3.    If the client jenny is unavailable, Twilio will request to the statusCallBack url with the parameter 'DialCallStatus=no-answer'. Now the following 
  twiml can be returned to say Unavailable message.
  <Response>
   <Say>
    Please leave your name and number along with a short message.
   </Say>
   <Record maxLength="3600" action="myapp/recordedUrl">
   </Record>
  </Response>  
 4.    Now the voicemail url can be stored when the "myapp/recordedUrl" is called once the caller recorded the voicemail. For more info on record verb, visit [this site](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record)
 Note that the voice mail is recorded on two cases, if the client is unavailable or the client does not accept the call.