# how to check Twilio Web Client online from twilio php REST

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

The scenario is  - A twilio web client  'Mr TWC' and A customer 'Mr 123'.

Now I need to respond 'Mr 123' based on 'Mr TWC' in online on a web browser OR offline/not on a web browser.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155664/twilio-browser-client-available-or-not/40380740#40380740">Here</a> is one similar question which I have answered. Hope it helps.<br/>

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid there's no way to check the status of Twilio Client users via the REST API.

There used to be presence events available on the Client, but this [was deprecated in version 1.3](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#deprecated-methods). So, I recommend you keep track of whether your users are online yourself. You could do so by maintaining a list of online users in something like redis on your server. Every time a user successfully authenticates and starts listening for incoming calls with Client, send an Ajax request to your backend to add their username to the list. Then, when they go [offline](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#offline), or [close the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload) you can send another request to remove their name from the list.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks philnash, 
I have implemented using MySQL the way you advised here.
 And sometime this fails which is Scary for me. 
Thats why I felt to ask here